# Can't remove PowerShell alias via ps1 script

Tags: powershell

Every time I run a script, I need to remove the curl alias from PowerShell in order to use the actual curl which is installed on my machine.

From PowerShell, I can remove the alias perfectly fine by using: `Remove-Item alias:curl`

But for some reason, when I put this code into a ps1 script and run that script, the alias is not removed.

Does anyone know why this is the case?

Comment: Is the alias not removed within the script run, or in the shell after the script has run? Scripts don't normally modify the "outer" shell, you would need to dot source it for a change to affect the shell after the script has ended. You can use curl by calling it `curl.exe` and then it won't clash with the alias, btw.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler I'm new to this stuff, so thanks for the easy solution :)

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler, good point about using `curl.exe` to bypass the alias. However, you don't need dot-sourcing to remove an alias defined in a parent scope, so Troy's symptom is a bit of a mystery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also update your profile to remove the alias each time PowerShell starts; `$profile` is an automatic variable that stores the paths to the PowerShell profiles that are available in the current session.

```
if (!(Test-Path -Path $profile)) {
    New-Item -Path $profile -Force
}
Add-Content -Path $profile -Value "Remove-Item alias:curl"
. $profile
```

Comment: Thanks for updating; makes sense re `Remove-Alias` (I hadn't realized that it's v6+ only).